# Pre-Placing Specific Images onto Objects in a Generated Image with ComfyUI

Tags: stable-diffusion, comfyui

With ComfyUI, what technique should I use to embed a predetermined image into an image that is yet to be generated? For example, I want to create an image of a person wearing a t-shirt, and I need ComfyUI to place a specific image onto the t-shirt. How can this be accomplished?